# Create a dictionary of dictionaries of frequencies from dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, machine-learning

i have a big dataset like this and I'm trying to make a dictionary of dictionaries of the dataframe to organize the column of 'crime' with the frequencies of the other columns.

train_data

```
    23  Wednesday  BAYVIEW  CENTRAL  INGLESIDE  NORTHERN  PARK  RICHMOND  crime
0   1          1        0        0          0         1     0         0      3
1   1          1        0        0          0         1     0         0      1
2   1          1        0        0          0         1     0         0      1
3   1          1        0        0          0         1     0         0      0
4   1          1        0        0          0         0     1         0      0
5   1          1        0        0          1         0     0         0      0
6   1          1        0        0          1         0     0         0      2
7   1          1        1        0          0         0     0         0      2
8   1          1        0        0          0         0     0         1      0
9   1          1        0        1          0         0     0         0      0
```

So i decided first of all to groupby the dataframe with the column of 'crime':

```
train_data=train_data.groupby(['crime']).sum()


       23  Wednesday  BAYVIEW  CENTRAL  INGLESIDE  NORTHERN  PARK  RICHMOND
crime                                                                      
0       5          5        0        1          1         1     1         1
1       2          2        0        0          0         2     0         0
2       2          2        1        0          1         0     0         0
3       1          1        0        0          0         1     0         0
```

And then i tried to organize them in a dictionary of dictionaries but i can't make it, i tried in some ways iterating too but there is something wrong with the dataframe.

The result should be something like this:

```
{0: {23: 5, Wednesday: 1, BAYVIEW: 0, CENTRAL: 1, ...}, 
 1: {23: 2, Wednesday: 2, BAYVIEW: 0, ...},
 2: {...}, 3: {...}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
d = train_data.to_dict(orient='index')
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html for more options.

Comment: Hi MaxNoe, i've already tried that, i receive the error: ValueError: orient 'index' not understood

Comment: Update pandas ;) `New in version 0.17.0.`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on pandas 0.17.0 or greater as MaxNoe posted:

```
train_data.groupby('crime').sum().to_dict(orient='index')
```

otherwise:

```
train_data.groupby('crime').sum().T.to_dict()
```